# How do I implement a gradle plugin which depends on an extension being configured?

Tags: gradle

For context, I'm attempting to write a plugin which will generate source code (Java classes), and it exposes multiple tasks (for different purposes). These tasks rely on information given by the user via extensions. Without this user defined information, these tasks wouldn't know what to do, and so they shouldn't be run at all if the extension hasn't been defined in build.gradle by the user.

One key thing to note is that, since I'm generating source code, I'm making the `JavaCompile` task depend on each of these tasks. However, I only want to define this relationship if the extension has been configured in build.gradle. How do I achieve this?

The following is a simple example for one task.

The `MyPlugin` class which is the implementation class:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
     // define extensions
     MyPluginConfig myPluginConfig = project.getExtensions().create("myPluginConfig", MyPluginConfig.class);
     ((ExtensionAware) myPluginConfig).getExtensions().create("fileConfig", FileConfig.class);

     // register task
     TaskProvider<MyPluginTask> taskProvider = project.getTasks().register("myPluginTask", MyPluginTask.class, task -> {
         task.getFilesConfigs().set(myPluginConfig.getFileConfigs());
     });

     // ensure JavaCompile task depends on this plugin's task
     project.getTasks().withType(JavaCompile.class).configureEach(task -> task.dependsOn(taskProvider));
}
```

`MyPluginConfig` is an extension class which just contains a list of `FileConfig`:

```
public abstract class MyPluginConfig {
    public abstract ListProperty<FileConfig> getFileConfigs();
}
```

`FileConfig` is an extension class (only used within `MyPluginConfig`) which contains the actual information the task may use to generate Java classes:

```
public abstract class FileConfig {
    public abstract Property<String> getX();
    public abstract Property<String> getY();
    public abstract Property<String> getZ();
}
```

And finally, `MyPluginTask` uses the information from these extensions to generate the Java classes:

```
public abstract class MyPluginTask {
    @Input
    public abstract ListProperty<FileConfig> getFileConfigs();

    @TaskAction
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Executing task...");
    }
}
```

In `build.gradle`, a user can now use this plugin like so:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.example.my-plugin' version '0.0.1'
}

/*
myPluginConfig {
    fileConfigs = [
        fileConfig {
            x = 'x'
            y = 'y'
            z = 'z'
        },
        fileConfig {
            x = '2x'
            y = '2y'
            z = '2z'
        },
    ]
}
*/
```

Notice that I actually commented out the `myPluginConfig` configuration above. As such, I don't want my task (i.e, `MyPluginTask#execute`) to run at all. With the way I've implemented it so far, it will run because of the dependency I created between it and the `JavaCompile` task.

An easy way to work around this would be to check if `MyPluginTask#getFileConfigs` returns an empty list. However, this doesn't feel "clean"? It seems a bit fragile since the business logic within the task could change in the future. Is there an official or proper way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe it could help to use NamedDomainObjectContainer and then register your task for every container that is defined via the extension. You can register to the container creation hook and register your task(s) with the callback code. This way it could be completely dynamic. See a great example at the end of this tutorial: https://dev.to/autonomousapps/gradle-plugins-and-extensions-a-primer-for-the-bemused-51lp